# Setting array upperbound in a generic class using Me.New()

Tags: vb.net

The following is an abridged version of the generic class example given in [MSDN documentation for constructing a generic class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/how-to-define-a-class-that-can-provide-identical-functionality). I have marked various statements with alphabet labels for ease of reference.

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim iList As New simpleList(Of Integer)(2) 'A
    End Sub
End Module

Public Class simpleList(Of itemType)
    Private items() As itemType  'B
    Private top As Integer
    Private nextp As Integer
    Public Sub New()   ' C
        Me.New(9)   'D
    End Sub
    Public Sub New(ByVal t As Integer) 'E
        MyBase.New()     'F
        items = New itemType(t) {}  'G
        top = t
        nextp = 0
    End Sub
End Class
```

I am not understanding the following points in the above code:

1. In `B` we are declaring an array type variable named `items` which can point towards an array. But this variable is not yet pointing to any array. Is this understanding correct?
2. The number "2" mentioned in `A` is passed to the constructor labelled `E`. And in `G`, an array of integers of size 2 (i.e. three elements) is created and the variable `items` points towards this newly created array. Also when `MyBase.New () i.e. F` gets executed it calls the parameterless constructor C.
3. What I do not understand is the following: What is the use of the parameterless constructor `C`? In the documentation, it is mentioned that the `C` sets the upper-bound of the items array to 10 elements. My question is:

   i) How does the `Me.New(9)`i.e.`D` set the upperbound? I am just not getting how `Me.New` is referring only to the array and setting its maximum size. Because ME is supposed to refer to the current instance `iList` which contains the array items and other elements!!

   ii) To set the upperbound, Can we not simply re-write `B` as: `Private items(9) as itemType`??

Comment: Your understanding of `B` incorrect, the variable is declared as an empty array. Your understanding of `MyBase.New` is also incorrect, it is calling the constructor of the base class. The use of the parameterless constructor in this case is to set the default upper-bounds of the `items` property .

Comment: @David thanks for pointing out the empty array thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong:

> Also when `MyBase.New () i.e. F` gets executed it calls the parameterless constructor C.

That line is calling `MyBase.New()`, not `Me.New()`. It is NOT calling the parameterless constructor of that same class but rather of the base class, i.e. `Object`.

Basically, if you invoke the constructor with a parameter then you create an array with that upper bound and if you call the parameterless constructor then it calls the other constructor with an upper bound of 9. In effect, you can specify an upper bound and, if you don't, it defaults to 9.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. One follow-up question: As you pointed out, `MyBase.New()` is calling the default constructor of the OBJECT class but does that  do anything useful? I get no error when I delete the statement but I am asking performance-wise.

Comment: @Sougata, invoking the `Object` constructor explicitly is indeed redundant. It will be done implicitly anyway.